# Unable to open appimage in PopOs 22

Tags: pop-os, appimage

I am using PopOs 22. I am not able to download Etcher using the appimage file available on their official website. I was easily able to open it in the previous distributions just by double-clicking but on PopOs it does not open. I searched quite a but about this but couldn't find a fix. These are some things I have done trying to fix the issue.

1. Changed the file permissions. Now it looks like this.

[image]

2. Tried to create an executable by entering `chmod +x balenaEtcher-1.7.9-x64.AppImage`  in the directory where the appimage file exists.

I still can not open the appimage file after making the above 2 changes.

Using the Deb repos:

I tried installing Etcher using the deb repos as well but it does not install successfully even using this method. It says `chmod: balena-etcher-electron: no such file or directory` at the end of the installation. This installs  Etcher on the system though (I can see it in the list of applications) but when I try to open it, nothing happens, I cant open this app either. [This is the link that I followed](https://github.com/balena-io/etcher?d_id=b2976e39-f113-40dd-96f4-2328e2801ac2R#debian-and-ubuntu-based-package-repository-gnulinux-x86x64)
[image]

There are alternatives for Etcher so this is not a huge issue (PopOs has pre-installed popsicle for burning iso files). However, I really like this distro and I want to stick with it. Not being able to open appimage files is a concern for me. Any help with this issue is appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Errors on console when I run ./*.AppImage

```
[Axios v1.7.9] Transitional option 'clarifyTimeoutError' has been deprecated since v1.0.0 and will be removed in the near future
[Axios v1.7.9] Transitional option 'forcedJSONParsing' has been deprecated since v1.0.0 and will be removed in the near future
[Axios v1.7.9] Transitional option 'silentJSONParsing' has been deprecated since v1.0.0 and will be removed in the near future
[4724:0828/182040.725841:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(415)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
/tmp/.mount_balenacTllMg/balena-etcher-electron: line 10:  4724 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) "${script_dir}"/balena-etcher-electron.bin "$@"
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you try to run the appimage?  The GUI might hide the errors, so also try to run the appimage from a terminal to see if it produces anything.

Comment: @GracefulRestart  sorry for the late reply. I just edited my question and added the console errors.

Comment: @KeyShoe May I ask what you are going to use Etcher for? If it is to make a bootable USB, I'd like to recommend [Ventoy](https://www.ventoy.net/en/index.html) - this tool is *insane*: you just create a USB stick with it and you can just throw in the raw `.iso` images onto the drive; no need to reformat or anything. To answer your question though: IIRC, the "GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye." error is related to Electron, so it is a problem with the wrapper. Can't recall where I read it, though.

Comment: @telometto I tried Ventoy today and it indeed is insane, I loved it. What about appimage problem though?. I put a fresh install of Linux Mint 21 today and downloaded the Etcher appimage (just to check) right after `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y`. The appimage opened immediately. However, I installed my NVIDIA proprietary drivers right after this, rebooted the system and re-ran the appimage. Doesnt open anymore. When I run the appimage on the terminal, I get the same error as mentioned. I think it is something to do with the NVIDIA driver?? Doesnt make sense but this is an observation.

Comment: @KeyShoe Check my answer. If that doesn't work, I'm unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
./your-balena.AppImage --disable-gpu-sandbox
```

I suspect it's got something to do with the sandboxing for some reason. Probably a bug and should be reported.

Comment: Works. Thank you.